# Waterwheel movement due to gate removing

Tags: energy, fluid-dynamics, flow

I'm not a physicist so probably my question is simple but it's interesting to me to know the answer.

If I have a waterwheel with a controllable gate as in the attached illustration, and I open this gate and the water flows and move the wheel, 1. What's the physical power or character that causes the wheel to move? Is it inertia, gravitation (of the falling water), or my power that remove the gate (and then I'll ask: how long this power that I released by removing the gate, influences directly on it?) or maybe other forces. I'd like to know how a physicist sees this in physics field eyes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We'll view things slightly differently depending on how you define the system.  In this system as you describe it, with a gate, some water, and a wheel, the power would come from the water's loss of potential energy.  It had more energy at the top, and it has less at the bottom.

There are other ways to view it, of course, but many of them make causality murky.  You mention the power that removed the gate as a "cause."  Whether that qualifies as a cause actually steps into the realm of philosophy, and shows up in all sorts of places (like the question of whether guns kill people or people kill people).  The science arguments tend to stay away from this sort of highly politicizable thinking.  Unless there's a really strong reason to say otherwise, the wheels turning would be "caused" by the loss of potential energy in the water.   If something is gaining energy, such as a wheel starting to turn, we tend to declare that it was caused by something that lost the same amount of energy, because in nearly all systems energy is neither created nor destroyed.